# SwiftUI .toolbar disappears after following NavigationLink and coming back

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I've added a .toolbar to the top level of a NavigationView that will eventually be used to select items in a list without using swipe gestures (up button, down button, etc.).  I also have a .navigationBar going on, to access other views for Account and Settings.

For the most part it's looking really good, but when I follow a NavigationLink (in .navigationBarItems) within NavigationView, **and then use the built-in back navigation**, my .toolbar disappears from the top level.

Am I putting the .toolbar in the wrong place?  It feels like a problem with .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) because when I comment that out, the toolbar will not disappear upon navigation... but I don't like how the default behavior works in landscape so I'm relying on it.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

                NavigationView {

                    List {
                        Group {
                            Section(header: Text("List Items").foregroundColor(.gray).font(.footnote)) {
                                Text("List Item One")
                                Text("List Item Two")
                                Text("List Item Three")
                            }
                        }
                   }.navigationTitle("Top Level List").navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                       .ignoresSafeArea(.all)

    // MARK: NAVBAR

                        .navigationBarItems(
                            leading:
                            NavigationLink(destination: UserView()) {
                                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle").font(.title2)
                            },
                            trailing:
                                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                                    Image(systemName: "gear").font(.title2)
                                })

     //MARK: - CONTENT NAV

                        .toolbar {

                            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {

                                Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Mute", systemImage: "speaker.slash.fill")})
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Repeat", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise")})
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Previous", systemImage: "arrow.up")})
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Next", systemImage: "arrow.down")})
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Select", systemImage: "arrow.right")})

                            }
                        }
                }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
}

struct UserView: View {

    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {

                    Form {
                        TextField("Username", text: $username)
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Account").font(.subheadline)

    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State private var setting1: String = ""
    @State private var setting2: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        Form {
            TextField("Setting One", text: $setting1)
            SecureField("Setting Two", text: $setting2)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings").font(.subheadline)

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: See found workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127277/12299030

Answer (score 1):

You right, it's in a wrong place. Here is how it should be if you need a toolbar always shown:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Group {
                    Section(header: Text("List Items").foregroundColor(.gray).font(.footnote)) {
                        Text("List Item One")
                        Text("List Item Two")
                        Text("List Item Three")
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Top Level List").navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            // MARK: NAVBAR
            
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                        NavigationLink(destination: UserView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle").font(.title2)
                        },
                    trailing:
                        NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "gear").font(.title2)
                        })
            
            //MARK: - CONTENT NAV
            
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .toolbar {
                
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Mute", systemImage: "speaker.slash.fill")})
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Repeat", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise")})
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Previous", systemImage: "arrow.up")})
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Next", systemImage: "arrow.down")})
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Select", systemImage: "arrow.right")})
                    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more SwiftUI adapted approach to solve the problem of the disappearing toolbar (navigation bar) in SwiftUI and iOS.
I use the toolbar for very essential commands - a replacement of the application menu in macOS. So, an absent toolbar cripples my iOS application. It should never(!) happen. However a variety of situations made it disappearing (like when I dismiss a pop-up view or scrolling in the main view). For this, I seemed to have found a solid solution.
First the template code to generate the toolbar - this is symbolic code for generating the basic content view in my application.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
      }
   }
}
```

My solution was that if I can not prevent the system from making these decisions not to show the toolbar I can try to undo the hiding by setting a State variable navigationBarIsHidden to false.

Here the updated code setting the State variable naviationBarIsHidden to false upon receiving a notification "renewToolbar". Note the modifier `.navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)` for the ContentView and the delayed change of navigationBarIsHidden to false via a `Task()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   let document:ApplicationDocument
   
   @State var navigationBarIsHidden : Bool = false
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
         .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document), perform: { notification in
            self.navigationBarIsHidden = true
            Task() {@MainActor () -> Void in 
            try? await Task.sleep(for:.milliseconds(1000))
               self.navigationBarIsHidden = false 
            }})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
       .navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
      }
   }
}
```

The question remained: when should I send this notification if such a variety of events can cause the navigation bar to disappear ? The solution was to bind this to a .onDisappear modifier of one of the Toolbar items themself.

So here is the complete code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   let document:ApplicationDocument
   
   @State var navigationBarIsHidden : Bool = false
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
         .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document), perform: { notification in
            self.navigationBarIsHidden.toggle()
            Task() {@MainActor () -> Void in
            try? await Task.sleep(for:.milliseconds(1000)) 
               self.navigationBarIsHidden.toggle()
            }})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
       .navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
            .onDisappear(perform: {
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document)
            })
      }
   }
}
```

In my real application I have the notification actually bound to a TextField (a search field) not to a Text, just in case this is not called for a Text.

The result is that the toolbar still disappears when I dismiss a pop-up view but it reappears immediately thereafter.

I tried the solution with renewing the id of a view as proposed above. It did not work for me. Replacing an id is a heavy action in SwiftUI because if force the re-rendering of the entire view hierarchy. The entire view (in my case: the entire screen) rebuilds.