# swiftUI bottomBar toolbar disappears when going back

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have these swiftUI views and trying to use the `toolbar` (bottomBar). When you launch the app it appears fine, but after going to `View2` using he navigationLink and then go back to the main view the toolbar disappears. It happens when the NavigationLink being inside the list. If you don't use a list (put the navigation link inside a VStack or similar) it works as expected and the toolbar reappears when you go back to the initial view. Is there a way to fix this?[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("View2")
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("go to View2")
                }
                
            }
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar, content: {
                    Text("toolbar item 1")
                })
            })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This was already reported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956668/swiftui-toolbar-disappears-after-following-navigationlink-and-coming-back

Answer (score 16, accepted):

##### Update: Fixed in Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

This is known bug. Here is possible workaround - force refresh on View2 disappeared (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var refresh = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination:
                        View2().onDisappear { refresh = UUID() }) { // << here !!
                    Text("go to View2")
                }
            }
            .toolbar(content: {
                 ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar, content: {
                      Text("toolbar item 1")
                 })
            }).id(refresh)                     // << here !!

        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround. It works with xCode 12.2 as well

Comment: Does not work for me. XCode 12.4 (12D4e).

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 12.4 - almost forgot to include the onDisappear method which refreshes the ID. Thanks!

Comment: any solution or recommendation? @asperi 's solution doesn't work for my situation

Comment: but in the provided example, toolbar doesn't disappear even without using 'refresh'
however, in my case, for keyboard toolbar, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This way is simpler and will help some people.

```
.toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(id: UUID().uuidString, placement: .bottomBar, showsByDefault: true) {
            AssetToolbarView(selectedCount: 0)
      }        
}
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked. I had been using ToolbarItemGroups, so switched to just ToolbarItem. I only needed to do this on one of the two items to get the toolbar to show up when returning to the parent view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to make sure that the toolbar is **only** visible in View1. To get this working I used a state variable to detect when View1 is viewed to the user.

```
 struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View2")
    }
 }

struct View1: View {
    @State private var refresh = UUID()
    @State var isShown = true
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        View2()
                            .onDisappear(perform: {
                                    if (isShown) {
                                        refresh = UUID()
                                    }
                            })
                            .onAppear(perform: { isShown = false })
                    ){
                       Text("Row1")
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    isShown = true
                })
                .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: {
                        // Action
                    }) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                    }}
                })
                .id(refresh)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more SwiftUI adapted approach to solve the problem of the disappearing toolbar (navigation bar) in SwiftUI and iOS.
I use the toolbar for very essential commands - a replacement of the application menu in macOS. So, an absent toolbar cripples my iOS application. It should never(!) happen. However a variety of situations made it disappearing (like when I dismiss a pop-up view or scrolling in the main view). For this, I seemed to have found a solid solution.
First the template code to generate the toolbar - this is symbolic code for generating the basic content view in my application.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
      }
   }
}
```

My solution was that if I can not prevent the system from making these decisions not to show the toolbar I can try to undo the hiding by setting a State variable navigationBarIsHidden to false.

Here the updated code setting the State variable naviationBarIsHidden to false upon receiving a notification "renewToolbar". Note the modifier `.navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)` for the ContentView and the delayed change of navigationBarIsHidden to false via a `Task()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   let document:ApplicationDocument
   
   @State var navigationBarIsHidden : Bool = false
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
         .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document), perform: { notification in
            self.navigationBarIsHidden = true
            Task() {
               self.navigationBarIsHidden = false 
            }})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
       .navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
      }
   }
}
```

The question remained: when should I send this notification if such a variety of events can cause the navigation bar to disappear ? The solution was to bind this to a .onDisappear modifier of one of the Toolbar items themself.

So here is the complete code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   let document:ApplicationDocument
   
   @State var navigationBarIsHidden : Bool = false
   
   var body: some View {
      
      // The NavigationStack ensures the presence of the navigationBar (toolBar)
      let theView =
      NavigationStack(root: {self.generateContentView()})
         .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document), perform: { notification in
            self.navigationBarIsHidden.toggle()
            Task() {
               self.navigationBarIsHidden.toggle()
            }})
      
      return theView
   }
   
   func generateContentView() -> some View {
      let theView =
         Text("This is my content view")
       .toolbar {self.generateToolBar()}
       .navigationBarHidden(self.navigationBarIsHidden)
   }

   @ToolbarContentBuilder
   func generateToolBar() -> some ToolbarContent {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Text("This is a toolbar item")
            .onDisappear(perform: {
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "renewToolbar"), object: self.document)
            })
      }
   }
}
```

In my real application I have the notification actually bound to a TextField (a search field) not to a Text, just in case this is not called for a Text.

The result is that the toolbar still disappears when I dismiss a pop-up view but it reappears immediately thereafter.

I tried the solution with renewing the id of a view as proposed above. It did not work for me. Replacing an id is a heavy action in SwiftUI because if force the re-rendering of the entire view hierarchy. The entire view (in my case: the entire screen) rebuilds.