# SwiftUI toolbar .bottomBar button doesn't trigger when user configures accessibility1 size or larger

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, bottombar

How can I accommodate user accessibility sizes with a bottomBar button?

With accessibility1 or larger user-configured in iOS, a bottomBar button fails to trigger. Smaller font sizes work. Configuring the toolbar placement to .navigation works.

Details: Navigate from ContentView > FirstView > SecondView, then back to the FirstView via the "Goodbye" bottomBar button displays the FirstView. Then FirstView's "Goodbye" button does not trigger. There is a user-workaround: in this situation, scroll the FirstView down to hide the Goodbye button, release, it returns, then press and it works. Code is below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showFirstView: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text("Hello, world!")
        Button("First View") { showFirstView = true }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showFirstView) {
        FirstView()
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State var showSecondView: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            Button("Second View") { showSecondView = true }
        }
        .toolbar {
            // On return from SecondView with accessibility1
            // or large text size configured, the button below
            // does not trigger (even with a programmatically limited
            // font size via .dynamicTypeSize).
            
            // However, scroll the view down slightly to hide the button,
            // let it return on screen, then the Goodbye button works.
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button("Goodbye") { dismiss() }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
        SecondView()
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack { Text("Second View") }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button("Goodbye") { dismiss() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The technique @Asperi shared in the post, [StackOverflow Toolbar disappears when going back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126986/swiftui-bottombar-toolbar-disappears-when-going-back), resolves my problem. See Update (1), Update (2), and Update (3) below.

```
struct FirstView: View {
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State var showSecondView: Bool = false
@State private var refresh = UUID() // <- Update (1)
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            Button("Second View") { showSecondView = true }
        }
        .toolbar {
            // On return from SecondView with accessibility1
            // or larger text size configured, the button below
            // does not trigger (even with a programmatically limited
            // font size via .dynamicTypeSize).
            
            // However, scroll the view down slightly to hide the button,
            // let it return on screen, then the Goodbye button works.
            // Or, change placement to .navigation and it works as expected.
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button("Goodbye") { dismiss() }
            }
        }.id(refresh) // <- Update (2)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
        SecondView()
            .onDisappear { refresh = UUID() } // <- Update (3)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If the question is a duplicate you should mark it as such. Don’t copy code from another answer and post it as answer.

Comment: While a similar remedy works in this case and for the linked issue, the symptoms of this issue, (1) visible buttons not receiving touches based on iOS accessibility font sizes, and the other issue, (2) a disappearing toolbar button, are distinctly different. Nonetheless, @Asperi's contributions for the other problem deserve recognition here.